# Save label on watchOS - swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, save, watchkit

I passed some label.text from ios to Watchos, in this way

Ios:

```
@IBAction func sendPara(_ sender: Any) {
        session.sendMessage(["a" : contoLabel.text! ], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)  
    }
```

Watchos:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        //Recieve a Message
        self.wcontoLabel.setText(message["a"]! as? String)
         }
```

Now, my question is..everytime I close the watchos app, all passed data was lost..in what way can I save all the data so the next time I'll run the app I'll have my passed data on the corrispondent label?

Answer (score 0):

/*you need to save the value in user defaults, then fetch the value on watch application launch */

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) 
{

    //save text in user defauld
    if let value = message["a"] {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "a")
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always save data in UserDefaults of watchos app , but as the apple watch has limited memory, it is reliable just to pass data every time required from phone.